# How to print xrdb/urxvt defaults?

Tags: arch-linux, rxvt, xrdb

`xrdb` prints anything that you have configured, but **how do you print the values for the settings which you have not touched?** Either generally for X resources or specifically for urxvt. The colour scheme, that is, `color0` onwards, can be found in an obscure [manual](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.1.pod#COLOURS_AND_GRAPHICS). Trawling around to find all the defaults is going to be tedious and error prone, since documentation could always be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The app-defaults file has that information, e.g., (depends on system) `/etc/X11/app-defaults/URxvt`

The `appres` command would also show this, e.g.,

```
appres URxvt
```

but there are compiled-in default values, for which only the manual is helpful.

The *classname* `URxvt` is pertinent, since you asked for the *default* (and that's what is usually meant in that case).  The instance name `urxvt` also can be used.

Comment: `appres URxvt` only shows the things I've configured through .Xresources, so that isn't useful. And `sudo find /etc/ -iname '*URxvt*'` finds nothing.

Comment: app-defaults might be under /usr/lib (but the package manager should be able to list the contents of that package, and be more certain).

Comment: `pacman --query --list rxvt-unicode | grep -i default` shows nothing, so I'm not sure what to look for.